# Set Attribute to ListItem in Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

From list i am populating ListItem for dropdown list.

```
var list = LoadList();
var listitems = list.Select(l => new ListItem
                            {
                                Value = l.Id,
                                Text = l.Description
                                Attributes ????
                            }).ToList();
```

On the Linq query I want to add attribute. Attributes.Add() method is not accessible. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN, the Attributes property is read only:

```
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public AttributeCollection Attributes { get; }
```

so you will not be able to do it using the object initialisers.

You could do this by doing something like:

```
var listitems = list.Select(l => { var li = new ListItem
                            {
                                Value = l.Id,
                                Text = l.Description

                            }; li.Attributes.Add(....); return li; ).ToList();
```